# LowDB get object with highest timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
      "log": [
        {
          "id": "H1AXR_ns7",
          "batt": 80,
          "lat": "lat here",
          "lon": "lon here",
          "tst": 1540552932
        },
       {
          "id": "H1AXR_ns7",
          "batt": 80,
          "lat": "lat here",
          "lon": "lon here",
          "tst": 1540531234
        },
       {
          "id": "H1AXR_ns7",
          "batt": 80,
          "lat": "lat here",
          "lon": "lon here",
          "tst": 1540511234
       }
  ]
```

In LowDB, I would like to filter and get the object with the highest `tst` value for the user with id: `H1AXR_ns7`.

I'm not sure how to do this:

I have the following code so far:

```
  db.get('log')
        .find(id)
        .filter().value()
```

I know that I have to write an expression in the `.filter()`, but I have no idea how to write it to get the higest `tst` for user with id `H1AXR_ns7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const id = 'H1AXR_ns7';
const getMax = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.tst < currentValue.tst? currentValue: accumulator;
const latest = log
  .filter(p => p.id === id)
  .reduce(getMax);
```

Documentation for filter:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Documentation for reduce:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

```
let [highest] = log.sort((a,b)=>a.tst - b.tst)

// highest holds that object now
```

Comment: I think he asked through LowDB query not this way.

Comment: no, `highest` holds that object `console.log(highest)`